# javascript submit() followed by self.close() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using a file upload input with an onchange event that submits the form and then closes the page.

```
onchange= "document.forms[0].submit();self.close();"
```

If I use just the submit() function the upload works but if I include the self.close() function the upload never happens.

Any ideas what is wrong with this?

Comment: Just a clarification quick.  How did you open the window?  Was it with `window.open` and does it actually close the window?

Comment: It makes sense. Why would the browser keep processing a form in a window that doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: You need to wait for the upload to finish before calling `self.close()`, otherwise you're closing the page before the upload completes - thus preventing the upload from completing altogether.

Comment: I figured it has something to do with the timing of closing the window.

Comment: You may handle it by giving the responsibility of closing the window to the targeted submission page, an empty page that closes at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You my friend are dealing with a race condition. Will the form go out BEFORE the window closes? You need to close the window when the response comes back from the server.

You can  resolve this by adding another call  **onSubmit** and then call the self.close() method. Add this onSubmit Condition on page or body load and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is because requests made by a browser run asynchronously and there is no guarantee the form will have successfully submitted when you call the `close` method.

Use the [`onSubmit`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp) event.